# Flutter,pubspec.yaml file is showing some errors

Tags: xcode, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

I don't know what is happening but I m not able to insert image through Asset image using `pubspec.yaml` file.Pub get is not loading dependencies.

Kindly please help me out. I am running a flutter project.

Here is the code of `pubspec.yaml` file

```
name: mi_card_flutter
description: A new Flutter application.

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# Read more about versioning at semver.org.
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    images/khushi.jpg
```

Error is :

> Error detected in pubspec.yaml:
>           Expected "assets" to be a list, but got images/ (String).
>           Please correct the pubspec.yaml file at C:\Users\khush\AndroidStudioProjects\mi_card_flutter\pubspec.yaml
>       Process finished with exit code 1

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So finally after spending 3 hours on this doubt.I got the answer.What I did is ran pub get from terminal and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Your indentation of the `images/kushi.jpg` is wrong.

Try the code below: Works well:

```
name: mi_card_flutter
description: A new Flutter application.

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# Read more about versioning at semver.org.
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    -images/
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Error detected in pubspec.yaml:
Expected "assets" to be a list, but got -images/khushi.jpg (String).
Please correct the pubspec.yaml file at C:\Users\khush\AndroidStudioProjects\mi_card_flutter\pubspec.yaml
Process finished with exit code 1   it is showing this now...basically pub get is not working

Comment: Expected "assets" to be a list, but got -assests/images/ (String).                                             what does this mean?

Comment: Expected "assets" to be a list, but got -assests/images/ (String).

Comment: Post a screenshot of the directory your image is @KhushiZawar

Comment: Also I have added the screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Please write in `assets` in `pubspec.yaml` file as shown below

```
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    images/khushi.jpg
```

instead of this

```
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - images/khushi.jpg
```

Comment: C:\Users\khush\Downloads\flutter_windows_v1.12.13+hotfix.9-stable\flutter\bin\flutter.bat --no-color pub get
Error detected in pubspec.yaml:
Expected "assets" to be a list, but got images/khushi.jpg (String).
Please correct the pubspec.yaml file at C:\Users\khush\AndroidStudioProjects\trial\pubspec.yaml                                                           Again same thing!

Comment: @KhushiZawar please also add your class file code where r u using this image?

Comment: Okay so that error got solved,now showing this,pub get is not loading 
C:\Users\khush\Downloads\flutter_windows_v1.12.13+hotfix.9-stable\flutter\bin\flutter.bat --no-color pub get
Running "flutter pub get" in mi_card_flutter...                     1.1s
Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: main dart code:  import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart'import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
void main() {
  runApp(Myapp());
}
class Myapp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 50.0,
                  backgroundImage: AssetImage('images/khushi.jpg')),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Comment: @KhushiZawar use CircleAvatar( radius: 50.0, backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/images/khushi.jpg'))

Comment: @KhushiZawar for your information your error is solved now I saw your included image

Comment: It got solved just now! Image was old,app was still not running at that time